# In ggplot2, remove superfluous points from line legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, scatter-plot

I have this plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris,
       aes(
           x = Petal.Length,
           y = Petal.Width,
           color = Species,
           linetype = Species,
           shape = Species
       )) +
    geom_count(alpha = 0.20) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
    labs(
        color = "Species (Line)",
        linetype = "Species (Line)",
        shape = "Species (Points)"
    )  +
    guides(
        size = "none"
        )
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I am trying to format the legend so that there is a legend that has point shapes (by color also) and a separate legend for linetype (also by color).

What I actually get is a legend just for shapes (with no color) and a legend for linetype that has colored points. I have tried every iteration of legend labelling that I can think of, to no avail.

**Question:** Keeping everything else the same, how could I get rid of those points in the Species (Line) legend? And how to add color to the shapes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to remove the color guide and override the aesthetics of the shape and linetype guide:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris,
       aes(
         x = Petal.Length,
         y = Petal.Width,
         color = Species,
         linetype = Species,
         shape = Species
       )) +
  geom_count(alpha = 0.20) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  labs(
    linetype = "Species (Line)",
    shape = "Species (Points)"
  )  +
  guides(
    size = "none",
    color = "none",
    shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1, 
                                             color =  scales::hue_pal()(3))),
    linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color =  scales::hue_pal()(3)))
  )
```

[image]

However, I might humbly suggest that the reason you have this difficulty is that you are mapping the same variable onto multiple aesthetics. This is completely unnecessary for a clear and legible plot - flipping backwards and forwards between two legends to interpret a plot just makes it harder on the reader, not easier. I would recommend getting rid of the chartjunk, perhaps something like:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, group = Species)) +
  geom_count(alpha = 0.3, aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_textsmooth(aes(label = Species), method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
                  vjust = -0.2, size = 6) +
  scale_size_area() +
  guides(size = "none", color = "none") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

I think this demonstrates the data more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I appreciate your suggestion about plotting philosophy. In my case, the study data are not nearly as cleanly delineated as these species data. I anticipate black-and-white printing, hence the differing shapes and linetypes. Labelling the lines is a nice idea though, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your use-case, another potential option is to add a new color scale using the [ggnewscale package](https://eliocamp.github.io/ggnewscale/), e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(iris,
       aes(
         x = Petal.Length,
         y = Petal.Width,
         linetype = Species,
         shape = Species
       )) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = Species), method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  labs(
    color = "Species (Line)",
    linetype = "Species (Line)",
  ) +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_count(aes(color = Species), alpha = 0.20) +
  labs(shape = "Species (Points)",
       color = "Species (Points)") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)),
         size = "none")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I was working on another project and discovered another strategy for making this happen. In this approach, you just have a single legend for all geoms. While more efficient, one drawback of this approach is that it may be hard to distinguish the geoms if you're expecting black-and-white printing (e.g., in print publications). I turn off the transparency in the lengend to address that, but still tough to see. So something to think about.

But here's the alternative (the trick is just to use the same name for each `scale_[geom]_manual()` function):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris,
       aes(
         x = Petal.Length,
         y = Petal.Width,
         color = Species,
         linetype = Species,
         shape = Species
       )) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x", se = FALSE) + 
  geom_count(alpha = 0.20) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Species", values = c("red", "green", "blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Species", values = c("circle", "square", "triangle")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Species", values = c("solid", "dotted", "dashed")) +
  guides(
    size = "none", # personally I don't want the size legend in this instance
    colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)) # turns off transparency in point legend; possibly easier to read
    )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>